# Basic FBJS in an FBML Facebook application

Tags: facebook, fbml, fbjs

I have tried just about every suggestion known to man to get the basic FBJS working in my FBML app.

Here is my code

```
<script>
<!--
function areyousure(description,id,opt) {  
debugger;
var dialog = new Dialog(Dialog.DIALOG_POP).showChoice('Are you sure?','Are you sure you want to delete "' + description + '"? This action cannot be undone!','Yes','No');
    dialog.onconfirm = function() {
        document.setLocation("http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/delete.php?rec
ord=" + id + opt);
    }
}
//-->
</script>


<a href="#" onclick="areyousure(arg1,arg2,arg3);" >click me</a>
```

When I click the link, I get a a1234543_areyousure not found.

Help Please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are messing a ";" in a href :

```
<a href="#" onclick="areyousure(arg1,arg2,arg3);" >click me</a>
```

Comment: I added the ';' and it didn't help. Updated the code to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters didn't exist. This works:

```
<script>
<!--
function areyousure() {  

var dialog = new Dialog(Dialog.DIALOG_POP)
dialog.showMessage('test','foo');
}
//-->
</script>


<a href="#" onclick="areyousure();" >click me</a>
```